# how to detect seasonality in a time series data in python without plotting it

Tags: python, time-series

Is there any way to detect seasonality in a time series data in python without plotting it.
I tried all the visual methods such as, plot the series,run sequence plot,seasonal subseries plot, box plot and auto correlation plot.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47369584/6121350) post uses autocorrelation to detect seasonality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are numerous methods. Search for "testing for seasonality", e.g. https://digitalcommons.wayne.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2030&context=jmasm